# XC8 compiler does not recognize __delay macros

Tags: c, xc8, attiny

I want to program a ATtiny85 microcontroller and have realized that my program needs a bit of delay to work properly. I am using MPLabX and the XC8 compiler. So I should be able to use the __delay_ms() macro and MPLab does recognize the macro and does NOT put the red line under the code. However when I try to compile the programm, there is an error thrown at each line where I use the macro. "Undefined reference to __delay_ms" And also an additional "implicit declaration of __delay_ms" for the first line that uses the macro. I do have _XTAL_FREQ defined correctly and xc.h included.

The code also compiles just fine without the delay macros, but than it doesn't work correctly, so I need the delay.

I don't know what the problem is. I have programmed other microcontrollers with the __delay_ms macro before. I am also using the latest version of the XC8 compiler. And according to the documentation of the compiler the version is fully compatible with the ATtiny85.

I also tried to find a solution on the internet, but didn't find anything that helped with my problem...

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: I thought MPLab was just for PIC, or...? Anyway, it's easy to roll out your own version of that function - simply use on-chip hardware timers.

Comment: Originally MPLab was just for PIC, but a few years ago Microchip bought Atmel and now MPLab is for both PIC and AVR mcus. I thought about using a timer as well, but I still wanted to ask this question, since using the compiler macros would be easier and would not require any of the hardware timers...

Comment: Well, each macro has to be defined somewhere. Have you searched the include files on the include path? Are there some conditionals preventing its definition for your target?

Comment: I searched, but I couldnt find it. All the xc.h include seems to do, is including a device header file, that contains mostly memory addresses for registers and the like. Maybe I am missing something, but when I open the xc.h file, it just contains a bunch of ifdef devicename lines followed by include devicename.h... That said, I also couldnt find it on another project using a pic I did a while ago, where the macro worked.

Comment: (Just a side note: Please add "@name" to your comment if you like to address someone. This will raise a flag in the recipient's account. I just came back by accident. The OP is notified automatically.) -- Well, if no header file (and I mean "really none of all header files in MPLab's installation") contains this symbol, I would expect that it is documented as "built-in" instead. At the same place in the documentation I would also expect which derivatives are supported, and how to declare the used derivative in the source or command line.

Comment: `XC8 compiler` this is just avr-gcc crippled by Microchip. Why not just using the real thing: avr-gcc resp. avr-g++?

Comment: I use xc8 for multiple reasons: 
- I use MPLABX and AVR as well as PIC MCU, all of which are from Microchip, so using the recommended compiler from the same company ensures the best compatibility. 
- I installed a version of avr-gcc once, but it kept forgetting the paths to its included libraries (That may have been just something stupid I did, but still ment that is was basically unusable). 
- BUT most important: If the avr-gcc compiler is structured the same way as xc8, using it would not fix the problem either. I fixed the problem with an additional include and definition (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did some more digging in the include directories for xc8 and I found something.
If I include util/delay.h I can use the functions, but only using one underscore instead of two. So the command has to be _delay_ms(). Then I can compile the code, but it is missing a definition for F_CPU. This however only results in a warning and not an error. I will try to find out where F_CPU is defined. I am guessing it is defined relative to _XTAL_FREQ somewhere...

I will keep you updated on what I can find out.

Comment: I couldn't find the definition of F_CPU, but its easy enough to calculate on your own. F_CPU just needs to be the system clock speed. That can be calculated from the clock source the clock selection registers and the prescaler. I got it to work like that now.

Comment: The macro `F_CPU` has to be provided by the developer. It might be needed to calculate the number of no-operation loops for `_delay_ms()` .

Comment: You said that you use the latest version of the compiler. They might have changed a function-like macro into a real function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be a comment, but I want to give you an example which compiles fine for me:

This is the way it works for a PIC

compiler: xc8 2.0

```
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ   4000000

void main (void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        __delay_ms(1);
    }
}
```

For an AVR it's a little bit different: (thats's crazy!)

```
#define F_CPU 4000000UL
#include <xc.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Apart from doing some more things in the while-loop and doing a little bit of port and adc initialization before going into the while loop, that is basically the same that I am doing. I am also using a longer delay, but I tried with 1 ms as well and it didnt work. And as I said, the other stuff I am doing works, when the delay is not there at all...

Comment: correct version of xc8? No problems with including `xc.h`?

Comment: Yes. I am using the newest version of xc8, downloaded 3 days ago. And the IDE doesn't see any problems. According to MPLab everything is fine. No red lines anywhere, nothing. The other things from xc8. like registers are working fine as well. As in I can use the name of the register to write to said register... When I then try to compile it, I get this error...

Answer (score 0):

And..  Microchip has changed things again with AVR.. This is with MPLABX 5.5 and XC8 2.32.

```
    #define F_CPU 4000000UL
    #include <xc.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>  // change to util from avr
    
    int main(void)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            _delay_ms(1);
        }
     }
`
```